# Couchbase retrieve data from vbucket

Tags: database, couchbase

I'm new to Couchbase and wondering if there is any manner to implement a parallel read from bucket. Given that, a bucket contains 1024 vbuckets by default. So could it be possible to split a N1QL query **select * from b1** into several queries? It means that one of those queries just reads data from vbucket1 to vbucket100. Because the partition key is used to decide which node the value should be persisted. I think it could be possible to read a part of data from bucket according to a range of partition key. Could someone help me out of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend proceeding down this route. If you are just starting out, you should be worrying about how to represent your data in JSON, how to write effective N1QL queries against it, and how to get a useful set of indexes that support those queries and let them run quickly. You should also make sure that your cluster is properly set up, and you have a proper mix of KV, N1QL, and indexing nodes, with none of them as an obvious bottleneck. And of course you should be measuring performance. Exotic strategies like query partitioning should come after that, if you are still unsatisfied with performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, I'm contributing to Apache Beam and just want to know if it is possible to do a parallel read.

Comment: N1QL fetches documents from KV in parallel. Checkout https://dzone.com/articles/new-performance-tricks-with-n1ql

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.